# How can I supress horizontal rules in newlfm letterhead?

Tags: rules, letters, letterhead, newlfm

I'm trying to use the `newlfm` package to put together a LaTeX letterhead.  (Thankfully, my college's letterhead is text-only, so I don't have to worry about fancy logos or the like.)  I've gotten fairly close to making it work, but `newlfm` insists on putting horizontal rules below the letterhead (and above the footer, which is currently empty.)

How can I tell `newlfm` not to insert these rules?  I know that `newlfm` uses `fancyhdr` under the hood, so I tried inserting the commands

```
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
```

in my preamble, but it didn't have any effect.  (Explicitly loading `fancyhdr` didn't in the preamble didn't make a difference.)  I also tried putting these commands inside the definition of the Williamsltr wrapper, but that didn't work either.  The documentation doesn't seem to mention these horizontal rules at all.

Any thoughts?  I'd like to use `newlfm` if at all possible, but if getting rid of these rules is more than a minor tweak, I'm open to using another package instead.

```
\documentclass[orderfromdateto,sigcenter]{newlfm}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{baskervald}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newsavebox{\Wlogo}
\savebox{\Wlogo}{\parbox{6in}{\Large WILLIAMS COLLEGE \hspace{5mm} \normalsize
WILLIAMSTOWN, MASSACHUSETTS 01267-2693}}

\makeaddress{WillPhys}{
\addr{ \parbox{3in}{\begin{flushright}\emph{DEPARTMENT OF PHYSICS} \\
  33 Lab Campus Drive \\
  Williamstown, MA 01267 \\
  (413) 597-2482 \end{flushright}}
}
\name{Michael Seifert}
}

\makeletterhead{Williamsltr}{%
 \setadrfr{\adrWillPhys}\Lheader{\usebox{\Wlogo}}%
}

\lthWilliamsltr

\begin{document}
\greetto{To Whom It May Concern,}
\closeline{Sincerely,}
\begin{newlfm}

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{newlfm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Upon further investigation, it appears that the header rule also appears on the second page of the letter, but (interestingly) the footer rule doesn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The width for those rules is given by `\@Hrw` (for the header rule) and `\@Frw` (for the footer rule), so it's enough to set those lengths to zero:

```
\documentclass[orderfromdateto,sigcenter]{newlfm}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{baskervald}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newsavebox{\Wlogo}
\savebox{\Wlogo}{\parbox{6in}{\Large WILLIAMS COLLEGE \hspace{5mm} \normalsize
WILLIAMSTOWN, MASSACHUSETTS 01267-2693}}

\makeaddress{WillPhys}{
\addr{ \parbox{3in}{\begin{flushright}\emph{DEPARTMENT OF PHYSICS} \\
  33 Lab Campus Drive \\
  Williamstown, MA 01267 \\
  (413) 597-2482 \end{flushright}}
}
\name{Michael Seifert}
}

\makeletterhead{Williamsltr}{%
 \setadrfr{\adrWillPhys}\Lheader{\usebox{\Wlogo}}%
}

\lthWilliamsltr

\makeatletter
\setlength\@Hrw{0pt}
\setlength\@Frw{0pt}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\greetto{To Whom It May Concern,}
\closeline{Sincerely,}
\begin{newlfm}

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{newlfm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Just add these two commands to the body of your document:

```
    \noHeadline
    \noFootline
```